# Best way to analyze an application crash

Tags: windows, crash-reports, crash-dumps, crash

I have an application, a game, that is crashing with the **0xc0000005** error. All other exe-files are working on my machine.

My question is if there is an easy way to find out what exactly is causing the crash (missing read/write permissions, dll's, etc.)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I tried so far:

- I ran chkdsk to scan my HDD > no problems were found
- I ran a memory test and tried different RAM modules on different sockets on the MB > the test found no problems and the application also crashed with different RAM modules and sockets
- I did a clean reinstall of Windows > the application is still crashing
- I tried to monitor the process with a tool called "Process Monitor" and I see that my exe is calling werfault.exe, which in my opinion should be right after it crashes, but before that I am not able to see the reason for the crash
- Windows Error Reporting says the following:

> 03.05.2015 15:24  Application Error   Faulting application name: GTA5.exe, version: 1.0.350.1, time stamp:
>   0x5540c256
> Faulting module name: GTA5.exe, version:
>   1.0.350.1, time stamp: 0x5540c256
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
> Fault offset:
>   0x0000000001606883
> Faulting process id:
>   0xe30
> Faulting application start time:
>   0x01d085b51e0c3aba
> Faulting application path:
>   D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto
>   V\GTA5.exe
> Faulting module path:
>   D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto
>   V\GTA5.exe
> Report Id:
>   32bf750e-a2c3-4002-bfa9-933bc2ad93eb
> Faulting package
>   full name: 
> Faulting package-relative application ID:
>
> 03.05.2015 15:03  Windows Error Reporting Fault bucket 86071493130, type 4
> Event Name: APPCRASH
> Response:
>   Not available
> Cab Id:
>   0
> 
> Problem signature:
> P1:
>   GTA5.exe
> P2: 1.0.350.1
> P3:
>   5540c256
> P4: GTA5.exe
> P5:
>   1.0.350.1
> P6: 5540c256
> P7: c0000005
> P8: 0000000001606883
> P9:
>   
> P10: 
> 
> Attached
>   files:
> C:\Users\danst\AppData\Local\Temp\WER121D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
> C:\Users\danst\AppData\Local\Temp\WER18B6.tmp.appcompat.txt
> 
> These
>   files may be available
>   here:
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_GTA5.exe_af4174c6205dd5b299c41ba6a62e7a294b66c7_d7c6dbf6_16411903
> 
> Analysis
>   symbol: 
> Rechecking for solution:
>   0
> Report Id:
>   4d902e1a-3113-4c27-85aa-224630761070
> Report Status:
>   1
> Hashed bucket: c7bb57dad94a180c3ac38b71b9c11492

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have the source for the application?

Answer (score 0):

Exception code `0xc0000005` stands for an access violation. The program tried to access memory that has not been allocated or is already freed.

Normally this type of exception is a bug. Either something failed to load/initialize by some unknown reason and subsequently causing this error or it is just some bad code.

You should report this problem to the developer of the software.